# VBA: validating no empty cells in ranges before proceeding

Tags: vba, validation

I have three ranges in a sheet (rng1, rng2, rng3) where I need to make sure that rng2 and rng3 contain no blanks before proceeding with the macro.

I have tried several methods that I can find and cannot get any of them to work. Willing to try a different method if someone has suggestions.

This is me trying to count blank cells using specialcells(xlCellTypeBLanks) but something isn't working with my error handling when neither range is blank:

```
Dim wrk As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim twb As Workbook
Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim finprod As Variant
Dim subprod As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook
Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(1)

For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
lrow = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = sht.Range("A2:A" & lrow)
Set rng2 = sht.Range("F2:F" & lrow)
Set rng3 = sht.Range("E2:E" & lrow)
On Error GoTo Err1
If rng3.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count > 0 Then
MsgBox ("Invalid item number.")
Exit Sub
End If

Err1:
    On Error GoTo Err2
    If rng2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Missing quantity.")
    Exit Sub
    End If
Err2:
    On Error GoTo 0

    Exit For
    Next sht
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to avoid using goto in such way - it makes the code confusing when it gets bigger. Here is what I came up with:

```
Sub check_blank()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim twb As Workbook
Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim finprod As Variant
Dim subprod As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook
Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(1)

For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets


    lrow = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = sht.Range("A2:A" & lrow)
    Set rng2 = sht.Range("F2:F" & lrow)
    Set rng3 = sht.Range("E2:E" & lrow)


    If Application.CountIf(rng3, "") > 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Invalid item number.")
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If Application.CountIf(rng2, "") > 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Missing quantity.")
    Exit Sub
    End If


Next sht

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) is **Nothing** when there are no [xlCellTypeBlanks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) cells available and Nothing does not have a count; not even a count of zero.

You can use the `On Error Resume Next` or choose a non-destructive method of determining if there are blank cells.

```
if cbool(application.countblank(rng2)) then
    'there are zero-length string and/or blank cells
    'do something
end if
```

The problem with the above is that the worksheet's [COUNTBLANK function](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/countblank-function-c72134a2-695e-43ab-a3f3-714aa770f385) will count zero-length strings returned by a formula (e.g. `""`) as blanks when they are not truly blank.

To catch only truly blank cells the following will be True - `CBool(rng2.Count - application.Countif(rng2, "<>"))`. Only truly blank cells will be counted and any non-zero count will be true. This avoids having to crash the environment with `On Error Resume Next` when there is nothing to find.

Comment: I chose Pavel's because I do have formulas returning "".  Thank you for the quick response though!

Comment: I am confused. If you wanted to count zero-length strings returned by formulas as blanks then the above works; as does the solution provided by @Pavel_V. If you only wanted to count truly blank cells then an alternate method needs to be applied.

Comment: Sorry, I read your post incorrectly.  One of my ranges has formula that could return "", the other range could have true blanks so I need a solution that can catch both (or two separate solutions for each range).

Comment: It's a bit of a moot point now but to catch truly blank cells the following will be True - `CBool(rng2.Count - application.Countif(rng2, "<>"))`. Only truly blank cells will be counted and any non-zero count will be true. This avoids having to crash the environment with `On Error Resume Next` when there is nothing to find.